# Error running rviz "undefined symbol error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEEb"

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is different from the solutions and questions that are already asked. I even tried to fix this with the already existing solutions although there differed by the "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEEb" part of the error message.

The whole cmd line says:

developer@haf:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1404305441.695792813]: rviz version 1.10.16
[ INFO] [1404305441.695862492]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEEb
developer@haf:~/catkin_ws$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182401/error-when-running-rviz-%22undefined-symbol-error:-/opt/ros/hydro/lib/librviz.so:-undefined-symbol:-_zn3ros7package10getpluginserksss2_rst6vectorisssaisseeb%22/) by [aboosaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19379/aboosaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw something similar recently. Try upgrading your installed versions of roslib and rviz to the latest versions:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz ros-hydro-roslib
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-03**:
Also, doing a dist-upgrade helps most often.

**Comment by [Dani C](https://answers.ros.org/users/12031/dani-c/) on 2015-02-18**:
Thanks Austin!

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-roslib
```

worked for me